# Hybris: How to add a product to a classifying category via impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

How would I add a product to a classifying category through impex?

Answer (score 0):

Just the same, as if you would add it to a normal category.

```
$productCatalog=productCatalog
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$productCatalog]),version[default='Staged'])[unique=true,default=$productCatalog:Staged]

INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];$catalogVersion[unique=true];supercategories(id,$catalogVersion);
;product_code;;classificationCategoryId;
```